# Cumulative probability of two events with a geometric distribution

Tags: statistics, cumulative-distribution-functions, geometric-distribution

Suppose you have a lightbulb which has an average time to fail of 5 days. The failure can be modelled as a geometric distribution. What is the probability of 2 bulbs failing within seven days?

Currently I have used the formula E[x]=1/p so p=1/5 = 0.2.

From there, I thought, well, a device might fail on day one and the second within the next six days, and a second possibility is that the device fails within the first two days and the second within the next 5 days, so:

[(cumulative density of failing at day 1) X (cumulative density of 6 days)] +
[(cumulative density of failing at day 2) X (cumulative density of 5 days)]...

and so on...

but I get a value over 1 which I don't think would be correct?

Any advice on how to approach multiplying cumulative densities

Comment: You can let $X$ and $Y$ be the first and second lightbulb durations.  Here you are supposed to assume $X$ and $Y$ are independent $Geom(p)$ with $p=1/5$. It does not make sense to talk about "cumulative density" here (in fact I have never heard that term before), but the law of total probability tells us that $$P[X+Y\leq 7] = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} P[X+Y\leq 7|X=i]P[X=i]$$ Can you operate on the right-hand-side?

Comment: Thank you very much. By cumulative density, I think I meant to type cumulative probability in r this is pgeom

Geometric Cumulative Distribution Function (pgeom Function)
https://statisticsglobe.com/geometric-distribution-in-r-dgeom-pgeom-qgeom-rgeom

could you explain the formula you have suggested in more detail?

I can follow where X and Y are less than seven but the but after is new to me

Comment: The standard **law of total probability** allows computation of $P[A]$ for any event $A$ by using a partition of the sample space $\{B_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$, which chops the sample space up into disjoint events, by $$P[A] = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} P[A \cap B_i] = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} P[A|B_i]P[B_i]$$ In your case we have $A=\{X+Y\leq 7\}$ and $B_i=\{X=i\}$ for $i \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$.  So $$P[X+Y\leq 7] = \underbrace{\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} P[\{X+Y\leq 7\} \cap \{X=i\}]}_{(a)} = \underbrace{\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} P[X+Y\leq 7|X=i]P[X=i]}_{(b)}$$ You can work with either expression (a) or (b) as you prefer.